# How to highlight Xcode cursor?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

How to highlight, change color of cursor in `Xcode 8.3.3` when `midnight` theme is selected? Changing cursor color from settings (see in screen shot) has no visible effect. When working outside in nature, can not see cursor.

[image]

Comment: you can see cursor option in your screenshot! tap on white color in box above it and you can select color of your cursor!

Comment: It has no visible effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the cursor color here

[image]

**output**

[image]